# Predict output gone wrong! - whats happening here while using "fprintf & stdout"

Tags: c, stdout, stderr

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  int main()
  {
          while(1)
          {
                  fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
                  fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
                  sleep(1);
          }
          return 0;
  }
```

The above program prints "hello-err" but not "hello-out", why?

Comment: flush the buffer `\n`

Comment: Google "_stdout is buffered_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

to stop buffering of the `stdout` or else you can flush like this:

```
fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
fflush(stdout);
fprintf (stderr, "hello-err");
```

From the C 11 standards §7.21.5.2 part 2:

> If stream points to an output stream ... the fflush function causes
>   any unwritten data for that stream ... to be written to the file;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can place a `\n` at the end of each of those `fprintf ()` calls, but you are probably looking for `fflush (stdout)`. You use this to, as the name implies, flush the output buffer.

Like so...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (void)
{
    while (1) {
        fprintf (stdout, "hello-out");
        fflush (stdout);
        fprintf (stderr, "hello-err");

        sleep (1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```